# Inyección de dependencias

Tags: java, diseño

Vengo a hacer una pregunta sobre el patrón de diseño llamado Inyección de dependencias.

> La DI permite a un objeto que conozca sus dependencias mediante una interfaz y no por su implementación. De esta forma, la implementación puede variar sin que el objeto dependiente se de cuenta. La gran ventaja de la DI es el acoplamiento débil entre objetos.

Entiendo de que forma funciona y para que sirve, pero no me cierra del todo.
La DI tiene la ventanaja de, como dice la cita, el desacoplamiento entre clases... pero tiene una gran desventaja: que al pasarle a mi objeto una interfaz, y no un objeto, pierdo funcionalidad, es decir, solo voy a tener los métodos de la interfaz pero no de los objetos.

Entonces, ¿Vale que un objeto no tenga dependencias, mientras pierde funcionalidad? Se que no es tal cual lo digo, seguro hay algo en lo que me equivoco y no tiene la desventaja mencionada. Pero bueno, hasta donde entiendo lo veo así.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero se debe comprender que una interfaz es similar a un contrato porque establece las funcionalidades que debe brindar quienes la implementen.

Esto provee la ventaja de que al cliente de la interfaz "no le es relevante"<sup>1</sup> el comportamiento interno de la implementación, en realidad lo que importa es que cumpla con la funcionalidad establecida por la interfaz. Si bien es cierto ya no se puede acceder a algunos métodos propios de la clase, pero lo que DI indica es que esos métodos no son relevantes para la funcionalidad que cumple la interfaz.

<sup>───────

1. Al cliente de la interfaz no le es relevante el comportamiento interno, pero a los desarrolladores/diseñadores de software sí nos es relevante. Esto sucede principalmente cuando se requiere cambiar de implementación para algunos casos en particular como por ejemplo aplicar optimizaciones u otros patrones de diseño.</sup>

---

Te pongo dos escenarios donde se puede ver la importancia de DI y donde los métodos propios de la clase no son del todo relevantes.

Escenario 1: Acceso a la fuente de datos directamente. Ejemplo básico de un patrón Dao.

```
//Entidad a utilizar con estructura similar a la tabla en BD
public class Entidad {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    //getters y setters...
}
```

```
//De esta interfaz, solo importa que guarde el dato y permita
//obtener dicho dato por su id
public interface EntidadDao {
    void save(Entidad entidad);
    Entidad find(int id);
    List<Entidad> findAll();
}
```

```
//implementación básica que utiliza conexión a base de datos
//directamente
public class EntidadDaoBaseDatosImpl implements EntidadDao {
    private Connection obtenerConexion() {
        /* obtiene una conexión a base de datos y la devuelve */
    }

    private int getIdGenerado(PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException {
        /* método que utiliza Statement#getGeneratedKeys
           y devuelve el id generado en esta sentencia INSERT */
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Entidad entidad) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO entidad (nombre) VALUES (?)";
        try (Connection con = obtenerConexion();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);) {
            pstmt.setString(1, entidad.nombre);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            entidad.setId( getIdGenerado(pstmt) );
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Error al guardar Entidad en bd.", e);
        }
    }

    private Entidad creaEntidad(ResultSet rs) {
        Entidad entidad = null;
        if (rs.next()) {
            entidad = new Entidad();
            entidad.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            entidad.setNombre(rs.getInt("nombre"));
        }
        return entidad;
    }

    @Override
    public Entidad find(int id) {
        Entidad entidad = null;
        String sql = "SELECT id, nombre FROM Entidad WHERE id = ?";
        try (Connection con = obtenerConexion();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, id);
            try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
                entidad = creaEntidad(rs);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Error al guardar Entidad en bd.", e);
        }
        return entidad;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Entidad> findAll() {
        String sql = "SELECT id, nombre FROM Entidad";
        List<Entidad> listaEntidades = new ArrayList<>();
        /* implementación para conectarse a base de datos, ejecutar el query y devolver todos los resultados como una lista */
        return listaEntidades;
    }
}
```

```
//Cliente de la interfaz Dao
public class EntidadController {
    //se declara un parámetro del tipo interfaz, no de la clase
    private EntidadDao entidadDao;

    //se habilita la inyección de dependencia por constructor
    public EntidadController(EntidadDao entidadDao) {
        this.entidadDao = entidadDao;
    }

    public void save(Entidad entidad) {
        //se puede validar que el objeto entidad sea válido
        if (esEntidadValida(entidad)) {
            //como puedes ver, de este objeto lo único que importa
            //es que pueda grabar la entidad
            //sus métodos obtenerConexion y getIdGenerado son irrelevantes
            //para el uso de EntidadController, no los necesita
            entidadDao.save(entidad);
        }
    }

    private boolean esEntidadValida(Entidad entidad) {
        /* aplicar validaciones sobre los datos de entidad
            antes de registrarlo en bd
         */
    }
}
```

Tal como se explica en los comentarios y como lo puedes ver, la clase `EntidadController`, que es cliente de la interfaz `EntidadDao`, no necesita conocer ni utilizar los métodos que no son públicos en la clase que implementa dicha interfaz.

Escenario 2: Se necesita utilizar una nueva implementación de la misma interfaz. En este caso, se necesita agilizar el acceso a los datos.

```
//se implementa la misma interfaz EntidadDao
public class EntidadDaoCacheImpl implements EntidadDao {
    //clase para obtener los datos de bd y almacenarlos en cache
    private EntidadDaoBaseDatosImpl edbdi;
    //cache, para tener los datos en memoria y agilizar el acceso
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Entidad> cache;

    //se habilita DI por constructor
    public EntidadDaoCacheImpl(EntidadDaoBaseDatosImpl edbdi) {
        //inyectando el bean
        this.edbdi = edbdi;
        //creando la cache
        cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        //iniciando los valores de la cache
        List<Entidad> listaEntidades = edbdi.findAll();
        for (Entidad entidad : listaEntidades) {
            cache.put(entidad.getId(), entidad);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Entidad entidad) {
        edbdi.save(entidad);
        cache.put(entidad.getId(), entidad);
    }

    @Override
    public Entidad find(int id) {
        return cache.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Entidad> findAll() {
        return new ArrayList<>(cache.values());
    }
}
```

Ante esta nueva implementación, ahora el cliente `EntidadController` puede escoger entre utilizar `EntidadDaoBaseDatosImpl` o `EntidadDaoCacheImpl` como implementación para la interfaz `EntidadDao` a utilizar. Sea la clase que se elija, los únicos métodos relevantes que el cliente va a utilizar son aquellos que se designan en la interfaz. No se pierde funcionalidad de las clases que implementan la interfaz, simplemente eso no se utiliza directamente por el cliente.

Ahora, puede surgirte esta pregunta: ¿Y si realmente necesito acceder a algún método declarado en la clase de implementación que no está en la interfaz? Pues la respuesta es **depende**:

- Puedes declarar dicho método como parte de la interfaz (esto significa que será `public` en la clase que implementa).
- Puedes crear una interfaz nueva con este método declarado y decir que la clase implementa las dos interfaces.
- Dependiendo de lo que haga el método, puedes sacarlo de la clase y convertirlo en un método utilizario en una nueva clase.

No existe una respuesta correcta a temas como este, se debe evaluar por caso y decidir lo mejor para la situación que afrontas.

Comment: Muy buenos los ejemplos! La parte del final es algo que también me estaba preguntando. 

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza es necesario utilizar una interfaz siempre para la inyeccion de dependencias?

Comment: @x-rw Es mejor usar interfaces que las clases concretas, eso se considera como buena práctica. Las ventajas de eso se explican aquí. Ahora, en Spring en particular, el beneficio de uso de interfaces para la inyección de dependencias permite además usar decoradores o proxies para agregar funcionalidad de manera dinámica sin modificar tu código p.e. `@Transactional` crea un proxy para tu clase y agrega el manejo de transacciones de manera "transparente". Te recomiendo revisar [proxy](https://goo.gl/fscazs) y [decorador](https://goo.gl/mtsq8M)

Answer (score 3):

Cuando tu declaras una dependencia a una interfaz es porque la interfaz tiene todo lo que necesitas para realizar la tarea que requieres de esa interfaz, si la clase que implementa la interfaz tiene otros métodos, estos deben ser irrelevantes para el código cliente.

En un buen diseño la interfaz debe proveer los métodos necesarios para que los clientes de la clase que vaya a implementar la interfaz puedan realizar su trabajo.

Es bastante común cuando se usa Dependency Injection que los métodos de la interfaz correspondan uno a uno con los métodos públicos de la clase que lo implementa así que esto no debería ser un problema.

Si deseas utilizar los métodos adicionales que no están en la interfaz simplemente agrégalos a la interfaz.

Answer (score 3):

> Entonces, ¿Vale que un objeto no tenga dependencias, mientras pierde funcionalidad?

No hay pérdida de funcionalidad, es algo diferente, una interface **es un contrato que define cierta funcionalidad**, por definición no puede limitarla.

Sucede que las interfaces introducen complejidad al código, pero esa complejidad esta justificada por su ventaja: Separar la funcionalidad de la implementación.

Imagina que diseñas una aplicación, arrancas por el diseño de componentes, entonces defines las interfaces de cada componente y las dependencias a otras interfaces, con eso solo ya tienes todo el diseño. Luego puedes implementar cada componente por separado, con sus pruebas unitarias donde *mockeas* las otras interfaces y pruebas cada linea de código del componente bajo diferentes condiciones bien controladas (por los mocks), y claro, luego puedes (o no) usar inyección de dependencias para "cablear" el sistema cuando terminaste todo el desarrollo.

Mas allá de las interfaces propias de Java, hay una serie de cosas que vale la pena separar con interfaces siempre que se pueda:

- **El modelo de datos**, la base, todo eso. La justificación no pasa por que, quizá, el día de mañana, cambies de MySql a Oracle. La razón definitiva es **que sea imposible, por diseño**, incluir detalles del acceso a base de datos dentro de otros módulos, haciendo el código mas limpio "por diseño". Ejemplos de interface: MiTablaN, y MiTablasProvider y POJO.
- **Red/Disco/Periféricos**: Es decir, Entrada Salida, y no devolver objetos tipo File o Socket, en estas interfaces retornar y recibir flujos de entrada/salida o similares. Ejemplos: InputStream, OutputStream, Reader, MiNetworkProvider, MiFileSystemProvider.
- Otros ejemplos: LOGS o registro de la aplicación, librerías de terceros (via wrapper), REST API.